# Angular two way data binding with banana box syntax not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to do a two way data binding so that a property (`file`) in the parent can be updated by the child, whenever the child changes it.

The value in the parent is only ever undefined. What am I doing wrong?

In the child component (`<cb-drag-and-drop-file>`):

```
@Output() public fileChange = new EventEmitter<File>();
private fileValue: File;

@Input()
get file() {
    return this.fileValue;
}

set file(value) {
    this.fileValue = value;
}

private setDocument(uploadedFile: File): void {
    if (this.isFilesizeValid && this.isFileExtensionValid) {
        this.file = uploadedFile;
        this.fileChange.emit(uploadedFile);
        this.isFileValidAndUploaded = true;
    }
}

private clearOldFileReference(): void {
    this.file = undefined;
    this.fileChange.emit(undefined);
}
```

In the parent component ts file:

```
file;
ngOnInit() {
   interval(1000).pipe(mapTo(this.file), tap(x => console.log(x))).subscribe(console.log);
}
```

In the parent component html file:

```
<cb-drag-and-drop-file fxFlex
                       [allowedFileTypes]="[FILE_TYPE_ENUM.Xlsx]"
                       [(file)]="file"
                       description="faslkdfjlsdkjf">
</cb-drag-and-drop-file>
```

Surely I don't have to imperatively set file in the parent, that doesn't seem reactive which is what I thought Angular was going for with the event emitter? It would also mean I can't use banana box syntax wouldn't it? I've added `fileChange` to the parent and it is never fired when I use banana box syntax.

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz demo for this issue?

Comment: @yurzui I have actually managed to get it working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f1t4wz) but I had to use a behaviour subject

Answer (score 2):

**Template** with "banana in a box" notation ("Das Runde muss ins Eckige"):

```
<your-comp [(file)]="file" ...
```

**YourCompComponent:**

```
@Input('file')
file: string;

@Output('fileChange')
fileChanges$ = new EventEmitter();
...
this.fileChanges$.next('whatever');
```

alternate:

```
private readonly bhs: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

@Input('file')
file: string;

@Output('fileChange')
fileChanges$ = this.bhs.asObservable();
...
this.fileChanges$.next('whatever');
```